# Regex to extract cents value from arbitrary currency formatting

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract cents value from next possible values using Java regex (thousand separator could be both dot and comma):

```
$123,456.78 
123,456.78 dollars
123,456.78
```

I have partially working solution:

```
[\.,]\d\d\D
```

The problem with my solution, that it doesn't work in case "123,456.78" when the last digit is the end of string. How can I handle this case?

http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/6af08221-63cb-4c5b-a865-c86fe5e825ff

Comment: So you want `78` as output?

Comment: Make that `\D` optional or yet better change your regex to something like `(?:\d+,)*(?:\d+)\.(\d+)`, i.e. match the entire string and extract the numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: Try `[.,](\d{2})(?!\d)`

Comment: Wiktor, it works, could you please create an answer and explain ?!\d part?

Comment: You might also want to try `replaceAll(".*\\.(\\d+)\\D*", "$1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\D` requires a character that is not a digit after the `,`/`.` and 2 digits in your pattern. If you want to make sure there is no digit without consuming (requiring it) use a negative lookahead:

```
[.,](\d{2})(?!\d)
           ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0GPqC/1).

**Details**:

- `[.,]` - a dot or comma (to support decimal separators in different countries, not just the U.S.)
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1 (since the `\d{2}` appears inside a capturing group `(...)`, you may access its value using `Matcher.group(1)`)
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead requiring the absence of a digit right after the previous 2 digits.

See  more about [how negative lookahead works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710).